# FCM tokens are not updated when all apps are backed up to new phones

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

After recovering backed up data, I expect the method `onTokenRefresh` to be called, but it is not.
Instead, when I first run the app, the method is called.

Since the updated token can not be updated on the push server, the new mobile phone does not receive FCM notifications.

Is there a way to force `onTokenRefresh` when backing up an app?
Or, Is there a callback for application installs?

Answer (score 0):

onTokenRefresh() is **deprecated** now.

You need to override new method onNewToken()

```
/**
 * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
 * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
 * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
 */
@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);

    // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
    // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
    // Instance ID token to your app server.
    sendRegistrationToServer(token);
}
```